# Find consecutive days per id for an event in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my dataframe:

```
employeeid eventid event_date
1          1       2020-11-01
1          1       2020-11-02
1          0       2020-11-02
1          1       2020-11-03
1          1       2020-11-04
1          1       2020-11-05
1          1       2020-11-06
2          1       2020-11-01
2          1       2020-11-02
2          0       2020-11-02
3          1       2020-11-01
3          1       2020-11-02
3          1       2020-11-03
```

I want to find the consecutive days, for each driver for event 1,

The output has to be:

```
employeeid eventid start_date consecutive_days
1          1       2020-11-01 2
1          1       2020-11-03 4
2          1       2020-11-01 2
3          1       2020-11-01 3
```

I tried a few things with cumsum() but no luck.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create groups for `1` and consecutive days per groups, filter `DataFrame` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with named aggregations:

```
m1 = df['eventid'].ne(1)

m2 = df.groupby('employeeid')['event_date'].diff().dt.days.fillna(1).ne(1)
m = (m1 & m2)

df['g'] = m.cumsum()
df = df[~m]

df = (df.groupby(['employeeid', 'g']).agg(start_date = ('event_date', 'first'),
                                          consecutive_days = ('event_date', 'size'))
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .reset_index())
```